# Falha no método SELECT da classe RANGE

Tags: xml, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

A intenção é que ao clicar na guia Sintese Euro, a macro imputasse na célula D1 da guia Síntese Local o caracter "L" e depois retornasse para a guia Síntese Euro. Eu consegui resolver o problema do erro imputando a macro no módulo. Dessa forma apenas inseri um comando na página Sintese Euro para chamar a macro:

Então na página Síntese Euro eu inseri o código:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Call Module1.Macro1
End Sub
```

No Módulo inseri o código da macro

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("SINTESE_LOCAL").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "L"
Sheets("SINTESE_EURO").Select
End Sub
```

O problema é que como utilizei o comando `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`, ele entende que todas as formas de acessar a guia podem acionar a macro, e como coloquei o comando `Sheets("SINTESE_EURO").Select`, na Macro ele acaba entrando em looping.

Existe alguma função que ative somente quando clico na guia e não em todas formas de acessá-la como é o caso da  `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`?

E essa é a linha do erro:

```
Range("D1").Select
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigada, gente.

Comment: Onde você está inserindo o código `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`? Num módulo? Poderia inserir um print da Árvore do Projeto VBA.

Comment: Então, eu não entendo nada mesmo de VBA, mas o código está dentro do “Microsoft Excel Objetos”.

Comment: O evento está sendo acionado da maneira correta. A célula D1 possui alguma ListBox ou é uma célula comum? Pois um teste com este código foi realizado e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Então, a célula tem uma listBox sim.

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa selecionar a Sheets("SINTESE_LOCAL") nem a célula "D1".
Troque o código da sua Macro1 por:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("SINTESE_LOCAL").Range("D1").Value= "L"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Evento Worksheet_Activate

Para utilizar este evento sem entrar em loop, você não pode utilizar o `.Select` dentro do evento.

Na verdade, [.Select/.Activate/.ActiveCell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982) devem ser evitadas quase sempre (a não ser para ativar eventos ou outras ocasiões que é possível somente com Select).

Então você declara a planilha `SINTESE_LOCAL` e insere o valor na célula ou range da seguinte maneira.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim SINTESE_LOCAL As Worksheet
    Set SINTESE_LOCAL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SINTESE_LOCAL")
    SINTESE_LOCAL.Range("D1") = "L"
End Sub
```

Você ativa a Macro da seguinte maneira:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("SINTESE_LOCAL").Select
    Sheets("SINTESE_EURO").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

O erro:

```
plan3.range("G4").select
```

A  mensagem: *O MÉTODO SELECT DA CLASSE RANGE FALHOU!*

O que foi feito (no lugar da linha acima):

```
plan3.range("G4").select
```

Faz-se:

```
DIM WsA AS worksheet
SET wSA= Worksheets("nome da plan3")
WsA.select
WsA.Range("G4").Activate
```